# How to use AgoraLive full SDK in my existing project

Tags: java, android, live, live-streaming, agora.io

i want the full sdk for the Single , Multi and PK live with gifting functionality that is in agora sample code link https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/AgoraLive . So please help me to use this with my appid because agora appid has the limited session time and some restrictions. For using this code, what should we do,should i purchase this code or pay for that . i only want to use this sdk code.

Apk sample in play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.agora.vlive

Answer (score 0):

To use this code and create your own project, you can simply clone it from the GitHub repo. Agora provides 10,000 minutes free every month. But to continue use Agora products after 10,000 minutes per month, you do need to pay for the minutes you used. Here is the pricing doc: https://docs.agora.io/en/live-streaming/billing_live_standard?platform=Android

Comment: Yes , but i want to use this sdk with my own appid if i use my appid all the RTM methods stop working because i think in the backend they uses their appid. So how to solve this